# Discord bot works fine hosted locally but if i try and host it on heroku it says "Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'"

Tags: javascript, heroku, discord.js

Discord bot works fine locally on discord server but when hosting on Heroku it says "Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'"
what can I do to fix this? (first time making a discord bot)

I am not sure what to do to fix this so haven't tried anything other than checking the code

the code should be fine because it works on my discord server when I host it locally
but all the code is posted here (https://github.com/MathiasAC/team-skylo-discord-bot/tree/master/SkyloBotDiscord)
also, I have removed the bot token while I get help it's normally there

I expect it to be hosted on Heroku but it says "Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'" even though discord.js in the bot folder and it works fine on my discord server locally hosted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have discord.js in your dependencies within package.json.

Run:

`npm install discord.js --save`

Then push it to Heroku.

Comment: Also, OP should remove `node_modules/` from their Git repository. Heroku will install dependencies during the deploy process, and `node_modules/` folders can't always be transferred between machines because of CPU architecture, OS, or other differences.

Comment: Since npm 5.0.0, the `--save` option is no longer necessary; modules are added as a dependency by default.